# Prove or disprove: There exists a ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove: There exists a ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

I think it is intuitive to try $\varphi: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi: a+bi\mapsto (a, b)$. Then let us check if this works.

- It is trivial that $\varphi[(a+bi)+(c+di)]=(a+b, c+d)=\varphi(a+bi)+\varphi(c+di)$.
- $\varphi(1+0i)=(1, 0)\neq(1,1)$.
- $\varphi[(a+bi)\times(c+di)]=\varphi[(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i]=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$.

From the above results, it seems that this definition does not satisfy the requirement of a ring homomorphism. Is there a way to modify it, please? Or is it possible at all?

Comment: One must change the multiplication operation on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Then such a homomorphism can exist.

Comment: @TheNumber: What is the multiplication operation on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @user99680 See the answer below.

Comment: The same as the one on $\Bbb C$.  The issue here is that $\Bbb C$ is a field, and homomorphic images of fields are again fields: it has no proper, non-trivial ideals (which are the homomorphism kernels).  That can be used as an alternative start for Prahlad's answer.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, how would you use use that? Note that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has subfields, for example $\{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No such homomorphism can exist, so long as ring homomorphisms are assumed to preserve unity.

**Main Result.** There is no ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* Suppose toward a contradiction that $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is a ring homomorphism. Then by Lemma 0 below, it follows that $-1$ has a square root in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Thus by Lemma 1 below, it follows that $-1$ has a square root in $\mathbb{R}$. But this contradicts Lemma 2 below.

**Lemma 0.** If a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow R$ exists, then $-1$ must have a square root in $R$.

*Proof.* I claim that $\varphi(i)^2$ is always a square root of $-1$ in $R$. To see this, compute:
$$\varphi(i)^2 = \varphi(i^2) = \varphi(-1) = -\varphi(1) = -1.$$

**Lemma 1.** For all rings $R$ and $S$, if $-1$ has a square root in $R \times S$, then it must have a square root in both $R$ and $S$.

*Proof.* Suppose $-1$ has a square root in $R \times S$, call it $(r,s)$. Then $(r,s)^2 = -1$. Thus $(r^2,s^2) = (-1,-1)$. Thus $r^2 = -1$. Thus $-1$ has a square root in $R$. A similar argument shows that it must have a square root in $S$.

**Lemma 2.** The element $-1 \in \mathbb{R}$ does not have a square root in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose toward a contradiction that it did, call this value $i_\mathbb{R}.$ Then $(i_\mathbb{R})^2 = -1$. Thus $(i_\mathbb{R})^2 + 1 = 0$. Now we know that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \geq 0$. Thus $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 + 1 > 0.$ Thus $(i_\mathbb{R})^2 + 1 > 0$. Ergo $0 > 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: That's fine, but you said that you are assuming that it preserves unity, so Step 1 is an assumption, not an exercise. If you don't assume that, then of course it can be the zero homomorphism.

Comment: ...and also assuming the operations in $\;\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\;$ (in fact, multiplication) are the "usual" coordinatewise ones.  As stated in the comments above, if the multiplication in the cartesian product is changed there exists not only a hom. but in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt, yes Step 1 immediately follows from the fact that $(1,1)$ is the identity in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. But if the OP didn't already know this, then it remains an (admittedly trivial) exercise. As for the operations on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, I think it goes without saying that we're viewing both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as rings for this question, in which case the operations on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ are given by the very definition of ring-theoretic Cartesian product.

Comment: It seems that the answer to this question depends on the definition of addition and multiplication. Right?

Comment: @XuS, yes. But rather than viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as a set, lets view it as a ring. Then $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has a very specific meaning. Namely, its also a ring. The operations are defined as follows. Given $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},$ the sum is $(x,y) + (x',y') = (x+x',y+y'),$ and the product is $(x,y)(x',y') = (xx',yy')$. The negation is $-(x,y) = (-x,-y)$, and the zero is given by $(0,0)$. These definitions aren't just arbitrary; they are the unique correct way of defining the [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29)...

Comment: ...in the [category of rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings). But this probably won't make sense from the wikipedia page alone.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ be a ring defined by operations $$+:(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})\times (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$$ by $(a,b)+(c,b)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $$\cdot:(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})\times (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$$
where $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ 
It's not hard to check the properties for a field hold, distributes, associative, commutes, inverses, etc...

Now define $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ by $a+bi\mapsto (a,b)$. This is an isomorphism.

So without defining the multiplication operation on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ a isomorphism can exist. But given the normal operation on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. no such homomorphism can exist.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such a $\phi\neq 0$ exists, then
$$
\phi(1)^2 = \phi(1) \Rightarrow \phi(1) \in \{(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)\}
$$
Also,
$$
\phi(i)^4 = \phi(1) \Rightarrow \phi(i) = \phi(1)
$$
Hence,
$$
\phi(a+bi) = (a+b)\phi(1)
$$
Can you check that such a map cannot be a homomorphism?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I do belong to the school thinking that rings have multiplicative neutral elements preserved under homomorphisms, but AFAICT that doesn't invalidate this approach to the problem.

Comment: Your second implication is wrong: a priori you could for instance have $\phi(1) = (1,1)$ and $\phi(i) = (1,-1)$.